# Filesystem slow after running out of inodes even after deleting files

Tags: filesystem, virtualization

I had the following issue the other day, that I "ran out of disk space" on a VPS in a VM. It took me a while to find out, that it was actually not the disk space itself, but that I ran out of file system nodes. `df -i` showed 100% usage. It then also took me even longer to identify the cause of it. It was the `/home/teamspeak/logs` folder which contained over 200k maybe more log files each 1 kb in size. And the teamspeak process kinda created a log file every 20 seconds over the past 2 years or so... lovely.

I then began to delete the files in the folder, which wasn't so easy actually and which took over 1 hour... `rm *` actually didnt work because of saying after a long time that the file list was too long. I then used the command:

`find /home/teamspeak/logs -type f -mtime +1 -exec rm -f {} \;`

Afterwards the folder was kinda empty and just showed up 17 left files in it.

Now comes the issue though... that doing a `ls` in the folder still freezes the shell for about 2 minutes in the folder.

Anyone know why? Is the file system broken now or something, is there a command I need to do to "clean up" or optimize the file system after an incident like this?

Comment: Can you please try a reboot and tell me what happens, when you use `ls`. What does `free -h` give you please?

Comment: The issue persists. Connecting via scp ssh gives me a disconnect for example browsing into the /home/teamspeak/logs folder https://i.imgur.com/mQULnEj.png doing a ls in the folder in ssh shell freezes the shell for a very long time and then shows the 17 files. Doing a 2nd ls actually afterwards is way faster though. Rebooting and the issue happens again.

Comment: I suspect this will solve issues without rebooting: https://askubuntu.com/a/620623/307523

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I tried a reboot and also a "power cycle", it is actually a VM VPS server. With no luck. The issue still persists after a power cycle. SCP SSH disconnectes me browsing into the folder, even it has just 17 files now in it. Doing a ls in the folder via ssh also freezes the shell for a long time and then shows the 17 files. Doing a 2nd ls is instant however afterwards. Rebooting, and the same issue happens of freezing.

Comment: ~# free -h: https://i.imgur.com/uIVFZNV.png

Comment: This took about 2 minutes to finish after a reboot: https://i.imgur.com/if965Fp.png doing a 2nd ls is instant afterwards. Rebooting and doing a ls and it freezes again for  long time. ls in any other folder works normally.

Comment: Memory is fine and shouldn't be the problem for the delay

Comment: I think I found the cause of the problem: https://i.imgur.com/b2Jo6f4.png Even after deleting the inode directory space is kinda too high, no? I saw this comment in a forum about it: "I suspect that the problem is because EXT filesystems do not ever reuse directory inodes once they are allocated.  To check to see the space being used try ls -l .. while in the problem directory.  If the size of the directory seems massive, your only solution is to create a new directory and move all the files to it and then delete the old directory." What should I do now? Why can something like this happen?

Comment: Thats a good point, thanks, I didn't know that. Have you tried it that way? Im sure why that happens, I never experienced something like it

Comment: But would that be the proper solution? Delete the logs folder and create a new one with the same name and rights? Why does fsck not fix this? I tried a forcefsck on / with no luck. Is there no command to optimize each folder again?

Comment: Sorry SSH is above my pay grade.

Comment: Interesting, I don't know, but please post when you do, Im learning with you now :)

Comment: I just deleted the folder and created a new one with same name and rights and the issue is now gone.