# Steam RAM use high after closing game

Tags: games, steam, ram

I recently got into Ubuntu and steam proton is working great. I haven't really had any issues with it so far. I did notice one problem. Normally my pc uses about 3 GB of RAM according to system monitor. After running a steam game and closing it, my PC is using 9 GB of RAM according to system monitor. I completely closed out of steam, but the problem persists. Furthermore, according to system monitor, I don't have any programs taking that much RAM, not even steam when it was still open. The one consuming the most is the gnome-shell at 287 megabytes.

The only thing that fixes is this completely restarting the pc. Frankly, I am going off of system monitor for everything, so it might just be a bug there. If anyone has had this issue let me know what you did to fix it.

I should clarify that my CPU usage is normal after closing the game.

It seems like the peak of RAM usage the game gets to corresponds to how much RAM is taken up after closing it. So, if the game only goes up to 7 GB of RAM while running it will be about 6 GB of RAM when I close it. Accordingly, if a game gets up to 10 GB of RAM it will be 9 GB after closing it.

Comment: It does it for all of them. Resident evil 2, Darkest Dungeon, and Terraria are the ones I tested. I am using Proton. Additionally, 22.04 LTS is the version im using.

Comment: I don't see a problem here, unused RAM is wasted RAM. The kernel is designed to make most benfit from your installed RAM and therefor keeps a lot of data cached and will free some RAM if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Nmath. I'll leave this post up just in case anyone knows anything, however.

Comment: "I should clarify that my CPU usage is normal after closing the game."  you can manually free memory unused (it will slow your system down for a little bit) but generally Linux will do this by itself when memory is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like I found a partial answer to my question in the following thread: [Why does ubuntu not seem to release memory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507699/why-does-ubuntu-not-seem-to-release-memory)

I am not entirely sure why this works or why it doesn't do this automatically, but you can use the following command to fix the problem:
sudo sync && sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3

I guess in my case steam is writing to pagecaches, dentries, and inodes which fills up the ram. The above line clears them. I wish this where automatic, and maybe it is if your ram is filled all the way up, but I figured I would post this anyway.

Comment: Linux *will* clear the ram eventually, and it will release the RAM *much* sooner than "eventually" if another program requests it. There is no reason to do this yourself; the RAM is available for programs to use even though it is reported as being used for pagecache.

Comment: That's literally what @Rinzwind said in the comment on your original question.

Comment: Thing is: this command drops ALL cache. So any active program is going to need to reload into memory making your system run slow (for a little while). It is best to NOT use it and let Linux handle this by itself. "I wish this where automatic"  it does only a little later than you want to ;)  "sudo sync":  find out the file that is cached and you can do `sudo sync -f {file}` and ONLY do the files related to steam.